# Tor Browser issue with DuckDuckGo

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, security

I don't know why today when I try to make a research the solutions appear within DuckDuckGo , a HTML??. It's automatic. I don't want this option.
I don't know how to remove that to stay on my "disconnect page like before (I mean Tor page only)

Could you help Please ?

Comment: I found what follows :                                                                                     "Just a heads-up, because DuckDuckGo takes user privacy (https://duckduckgo.com/privacy) seriously, search queries go directly to them, unlike other search engines which are proxied through Disconnect"                                                                                               I don't know who wrote that ? But how to keep Search disconnecteMe to have the encryption option (nobody can see what you are searching). Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the "encryption option"? DuckDuckGo returns results over HTTPS, so has TLS encryption by default.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks what is TLS ?

Comment: TLS is [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). It provides the encryption used by HTTPS, which is the secure version of HTTP.